# Bootstrap 5 Hamburger Icon Doesn't Show (Trouble with navbar-toggler-icon)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu, bootstrap-5

I have a weird problem where the navbar-toggler-icon refuses to show. It used to show it but suddenly something made it disappear. The JS is working and it does open the menu, but the icon itself refuses to show. Excuse my poor inline-styling and horrible bootstrap classes, this is my first website I ever made, and am still learning.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-3">
        <img src="img/brand_logo.png" class="d-inline-block align-top w-25 me-3" alt="Brand Logo" style="width: 5%">
        <span style="
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #105cd9;
        font-size: 115%;
        font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
        ">
            <b>Test Website</b>
        </span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#personalInfo" class="nav-link">Personal Info</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#education" class="nav-link">Education</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#workExperience" class="nav-link">Work Experience</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#recommendations" class="nav-link">Recommendations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you give it in code snippet?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 5?

Comment: I had the same problem .I used bootstrap 5 than I figure out the parent of my nav tag get inherited height and width from it's parent and I deleted them and it worked correctly.